# AudioKit - Remove AKNodeOutputPlot center line on launch

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Is it possible to remove the AKNodeOutputPlot line when an audio file has been analysed? I've looked at the API and I can't find anyway to either sets it alpha to nil or clear the UIColor().

I currently have this at the start but would like to remove it.

[image: Audio line from AKNodeOutputPlot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer is initially filled with zeros, so that's why you're getting the line. Perhaps you could add some logic to not draw when the value is identically zero.